# Bootstrap labels display:block -- make fill only half of table cell?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have a table with a label in it

```
<table class="table rep-cal-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>    
            <span class="label label-default label-cal"> Test </span>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the css for the label is

```
.label-cal {
    display:block;
    margin:.3em;
  padding: .3em;
}
```

With display:block, the label fills the whole cell. How can I chose to have it fill only the first half or second half (horizontally)? I tried defining divs with width=50% within the column, but that didn't work.

Comment: Try display inline-block and width 50%.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the label has a `display:block`, because some css rule is overriding your css. I've added a `!important` and it fixed the problem.

```css
.label-cal {
    display:block;
    margin:.3em;
    padding: .3em;
    width:50%;
}
span{
   display:block!important;
}

div{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="root">
  <table class="table rep-cal-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>    
            <span class="label label-default label-cal"> Test </span>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for the first part (having it half width), but doesn't let me choose whether to display it as either the first or second half of a column (horizontally). Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out put. its work with width:50% but you need to add width to the table

```
<table class="table rep-cal-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Monday</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td>    
        <span class="label label-default label-cal"> Test </span>
    </td>
</tbody>
```

```
.label-cal {  width:50%;
display:block;margin:.3em;  padding: .3em;border:1px #f00 solid;}table{border:1px #f00 solid; width:400px;}
```